# Warning: This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render

Tags: reactjs, function, return, components, warnings

```
const PersonDetails = () => {
  return (
    <SwapiServiceConsumer>
      {({ getPerson }) => {
        return witdDetails(
          withChildFunc(ItemDetails, withChildDetails(arrPersonDetails)),
          getPerson
        );
      }}
    </SwapiServiceConsumer>
  );
};
```

Hello there. Please tell me where my mistake is. I am getting the following error: Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.

```
Here witdDetails, withChildFunc and withChildDetails is HOC
If anyone knows the swapi, I have the PlanetList but the PlanetDetails are not visible.
```

Comment: Please help me ///

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty explicit, you cannot return a function as a React Child.

Either make sure the `withDetails` function returns a valid React Component, or you can create a new Component that will take the details as props to render them on the DOM and return that instead.

Comment: Hello there. Thanks for your reply. But I don't think so. I will try again.